# TypeORM fails to find a connection when testing an Express app with Supertest

Tags: typescript, jestjs, typeorm, supertest

I'm building a TypeScript Node.js/Express application and started implementing some integration tests with Jest and Supertest, but even after setting up a TypeORM connection successfully my tests fail saying that a connection was not found.

This is what I currently have in my test file:

```
let conn: Connection;

describe('tests admin routes', () => {
  beforeAll(async () => {
    conn = await createConnection();
    registerDeps(); // registers dependencies on my tsyringe container
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    await conn.close();
  });

  it('should be able to authenticate admins', async () => {
    const { status } = await supertest(app) // app is an `Express` "instance"
      .post('/admins/auth')
      .send({
        email: 'myemail@company.com',
        password: 'mypassword',
      });

    console.log(status);
  });
});
```

If I run `jest` on my terminal, I get the following:

```
FAIL  src/modules/admin/web/controllers/__tests__/AdminsController.spec.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    ConnectionNotFoundError: Connection "default" was not found.

      at new ConnectionNotFoundError (src/error/ConnectionNotFoundError.ts:8:9)
      at ConnectionManager.Object.<anonymous>.ConnectionManager.get (src/connection/ConnectionManager.ts:40:19)
      at Object.getRepository (src/index.ts:284:35)
      at new VideosRepositoryTORM (src/modules/course/infrastructure/lib/typeorm/repositories/VideosRepositoryTORM.ts:11:26)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/modules/course/web/controller/CoursesController.ts:12:26)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/modules/course/web/routers/courses.router.ts:5:1)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.89 s
Ran all test suites.
```

I'm a bit confused because none of the services my controller calls uses that `VideosRepositoryTORM` and if I use that `conn` to resolve a repository, doing `conn.getRepository(Admin)` for example (`Admin` being a TypeORM entity) and then call any `Repository` method like `find` or `query` it actually returns data stored on the database, which leads me to believe that my connection was indeed established and is working.

Also, my application works fine when ran with `node`, it's just outputting this connection error on the tests. And it might be worth mentioning that I'm using `tsyringe` to inject repository implementations into my services, but I don't think it is causing the problem. Does anyone have an idea on what might be happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening here is I have two connections on my `'ormconfig.js'` file:

```
module.exports = [
  {
    name: 'default',
    type: 'postgres',
    // ...
  },
  {
    name: 'test',
    type: 'postgres',
    // ...
  },
];
```

And, if not told otherwise, `typeorm` always tries to do stuff with the `'default'` connection. For example, loading an Entity repository with `getRepository(Teacher)` is equivalent to `getRepository(Teacher, 'default')`. So `typeorm` is in fact creating the connections, but it's trying to use `'default'` instead of `'test'` when I run my integrations tests.

There are a few things you can do to work around this when you're using multiple connections:

1. Hardcoding which connection you want to use every time (which will not work well for most cases);
2. Setting environment variables and using them to select which connection you want (which is the most flexible option);
3. Loading the desired connection configuration and "renaming" it to `'default'`, or whatever other name you may use, when creating the connection.

In my case I opted for the third option, so I've put the following in the tests:

```
beforeAll(async () => {
    const connOpts = await getConnectionOptions('test');
    conn = await createConnection({ ...connOpts, name: 'default' });
    // ...
});
```

If you were to use more than two connections the second option would probably be better, but the third would also work. It's entirely up to you to decide.